# React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I was using split function to split two string into arrays. The string 'myVar' responses on the user's change of the drop down menu in its child component, and 'myVar' will be a date range for example, 07/20/2020 - 07/27/2020. I have break 'myVar' into two parts 07/20/2020 and 07/27/2020, I succeed in splitting the first string 'startarr' but fail in splitting the second string 'endear' bcz of this type of undefined error. Does anyone have any clue on the issue?

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { WeeklyTrafficCard } from './WeeklyTrafficCard';
import { AppContext } from 'contexts/App';
import { API_URL } from 'constants/index.js';
import { todayOpen, todayClose } from 'helpers';
import moment from 'moment';
const WeeklyTrafficCardContainer = (props) => {
  const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState('');


  const { API } = useContext(AppContext);
  const { store = {} } = props;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const open = todayOpen(store.hours, store.timezone);
  const close = todayClose(store.hours, store.timezone);

  var datearr= myVar.split(' - ');

  var newstart = datearr[0];
  var startarr = newstart.split('/');
  var start1 = '20'+ startarr[2] + '-' + startarr[0] + '-' + startarr[1] + ' ' + '00:00:00';
  console.log(start1);
  var start = moment(start1);
  var finalstart = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss[Z]');

  var newend = datearr[1];
  console.log(newend)
  var endarr = newend.split('/');
  console.log(endarr);
```

Comment: Splitting an empty string will only give *one* item so where `newend = datearr[1]`, `newend` will be undefined.

Comment: I think instead of `newstart.split('/');` should be `newstart[1].split('/');`

Comment: @evolutionbox the string is actually not empty, it is a daterange like 07/20/20 - 07/27/20,

Comment: @Mario the Newstart is the the first part of the array after splitting ' - '(first element is start date so it should be 0) from 07/20/20 - 07/27/20.